# p-tableCheckbox check by default

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, primeng

I'm new with primeNG and p-tableCheckbox.
I'm using this component to create a checkbox column to check/select the right row. So the normal standard and behaviour works perfectly. But now I need to select by default some row/checkoxes by component.ts.

I'm searching everywhere and I don't find anything about this behaviour.

I tried something like this

```
 <p-tableCheckbox #tableCheckbox [value]="rowData" [index]="rowIndex"></p-tableCheckbox>

 checkSelected(event) {
    this.checkboxSelected.emit(event.data);
    this.tableCheckbox.checked = true;
 }
```

where but obviously doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

With p-table pass selected objects like

```
<p-table [(selection)]="selectedRowDataArray">
```

This will automatically mark required checkboxes as selected.

Comment: @Akash Garg But on RowSelect it is changing the state of checkbox

Comment: what do you mean, can you elaborate. in my method, if you change this selectedRowDataArray, your checkbox will get selected accordingly.

Comment: <p-table [(selection)]="selectedRowDataArray" selectionMode="single">
Above is my p-table configuration.

<p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"  binary="true" (click)="clickMethod(rowData,$event)"></p-tableCheckbox>

Now I'm having a p-tablecheckbox in the first column, now whenever I'm clicking on row anywhere checkbox state is changing from checked-unchecked or vice-versa.

Comment: what do you mean?